# How does one use an enum class as a set of flags?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have a set of flags and a class like this:

```
/// <summary>Options controlling a search for files.</summary>
enum class FindFilesOptions : unsigned char
{
    LocalSearch = 0,
    RecursiveSearch = 1,
    IncludeDotDirectories = 2
};

class FindFiles : boost::noncopyable
{
    /* omitted */
public:
    FindFiles(std::wstring const& pattern, FindFilesOptions options);
    /* omitted */
}
```

and I want a caller to be able to select more than one option:

```
FindFiles handle(Append(basicRootPath, L"*"),
    FindFilesOptions::RecursiveSearch | FindFilesOptions::IncludeDotDirectories);
```

Is it possible to support this in a strongly-typed way with C++11 `enum class`, or do I have to revert to untyped enumerations?

(I know the caller could `static_cast` to the underlying type and `static_cast` back, but I don't want the caller to have to do that)

Comment: There's also [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) to pass flags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is certainly possible to use `enum class`es for bitmaps. It is, unfortunately, a bit painful to do so: You need to define the necessary bit operations on your type. Below is an example how this could look like. It would be nice if the `enum class`es could derive from some other type which could live in a suitable namespace defining the necessary operator boilerplate code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class bitmap: unsigned char
{
    a = 0x01,
    b = 0x02,
    c = 0x04
};

bitmap operator& (bitmap x, bitmap y)
{
    typedef std::underlying_type<bitmap>::type uchar;
    return bitmap(uchar(x) & uchar(y));
}

bitmap operator| (bitmap x, bitmap y)
{
    typedef std::underlying_type<bitmap>::type uchar;
    return bitmap(uchar(x) | uchar(y));
}

bitmap operator^ (bitmap x, bitmap y)
{
    typedef std::underlying_type<bitmap>::type uchar;
    return bitmap(uchar(x) ^ uchar(y));
}

bool test(bitmap x)
{
    return std::underlying_type<bitmap>::type(x);
}

int main()
{
    bitmap v = bitmap::a | bitmap::b;
    if (test(v & bitmap::a)) {
        std::cout << "a ";
    }
    if (test(v & bitmap::b)) {
        std::cout << "b ";
    }
    if (test(v & bitmap::c)) {
        std::cout << "c ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think that is painful at all -- I only want to allow callers to OR them together so all I'd need would be operator|. +1

Comment: @BillyONeal: I'm opposed to any sort of code duplication. I would prefer if the operators could be conjured up using something like `enum class bitmap: bitmaps::base<unsigned char> { ... };` with the above operators defined as templates in the namespace `bitmaps`.

Comment: you could always stamp out the operators with macros.

Comment: Why not use `std::underlying_type<bitmap>::type` instead of repeating it in the typedef?

Comment: @DyP: good point: probably because I haven't used `enum class`es much, yet, and I wasn't aware of this type traits! I have fixed the answer.

Comment: BTW, the correct term is "bitfield", not "bitmap". A bitmap, particularly in image circles, is something quite different.

Comment: The `uchar` identifier can mean something other than `unsigned char` if the enum changes (far away from the actual operators, so out of sight). Why not just call it `type`?

Comment: "I would prefer if the operators could be conjured up by using something like `enum class bitmap: bitmaps::base<unsigned char>`" Could use [a class with an anonymous enum member](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/A/31f81324fe6f97ae), with the downside that the *enumerators* themselves are still implicitly convertible to an integral type :/

Comment: @DyP: Maybe I should settle with defining the `enum` in a suitable location and using a `typedef` to make it accessible where it is actually needed. [Here](http://ideone.com/FKiWX7) is a complete example.

Comment: Given that you have control over the semantics of `operator|`, you can allow it to work on bit indexes and forgo defining the enumerators as powers of two.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Interesting! (Any reason to use `noexcept(true)` over just `noexcept`?)

Comment: @DyP: The only reason to use `noexcept(true)` is to make more explicit. There is no technical reason.

Comment: IMO this is broken. `a | b` is not a valid member of `bitmap` yet through casting you are claiming it is.

Comment: @SheaLevy `operator|` is not a member of any enumeration. There's a built-in operator `|` (built-in = not a function) that operates on unscoped enumerations. You can also define (some) operators as non-member (= free) functions. In `bitmap(uchar(x) | uchar(y));`, the `|` is *not* operating on an enumeration type, but on an integral type, such as `int`.

Comment: @dyp that's not my point. With the way you defined `operator |`, I can create a `bitmap` whose underlying value is `Ox03`, but `Ox03` is *not* a legal `bitmap` value!

Comment: @SheaLevy Well there's no enumerator with the value `0x03`, but `0x03` is a "valid" value for a variable of type `bitmap`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/18195312/420683

Comment: "It would be nice if the enum classes could derive from some other type which could live in a suitable namespace defining the necessary operator boilerplate code." — you can leverage ADL, templating and the traits idiom to avoid boilerplate. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12927952/153285 . (Sorry for dead-posting!)

Comment: @DietmarKühl I tripped up on C-style cast you use `uchar(…)` mistaking it for the underlying type's constructor and that an implicit conversion is happening from enum to the underlying type - which isn't the case. Nice answer btw!

Answer (score 5):

Templates play well with `enum class` so you can define sets of operators that work on sets of similar enumeration types. The key is to use a traits template to specify what interface(s) each enumeration conforms/subscribes to.

As a start:

```
enum class mood_flag {
    jumpy,
    happy,
    upset,
    count // size of enumeration
};

template<>
struct enum_traits< mood_flag > {
    static constexpr bool bit_index = true;
};

template< typename t >
struct flag_bits : std::bitset< static_cast< int >( t::count ) > {
    flag_bits( t bit ) // implicit
        { this->set( static_cast< int >( bit ) ); }

    // Should be explicit but I'm lazy to type:
    flag_bits( typename flag_bits::bitset set )
        : flag_bits::bitset( set ) {}
};

template< typename e >
typename std::enable_if< enum_traits< e >::bit_index,
    flag_bits< e > >::type
operator | ( flag_bits< e > set, e next )
    { return set | flag_bits< e >( next ); }

template< typename e >
typename std::enable_if< enum_traits< e >::bit_index,
    flag_bits< e > >::type
operator | ( e first, e next )
    { return flag_bits< e >( first ) | next; }
```

http://ideone.com/kJ271Z

GCC 4.9 reported that some implicit member functions were `constexpr` while I was getting this to compile, so the templates should probably be so as well.

This should probably also have a free function `to_scalar` or something which returns an unsigned integer type given either an individual flag or a `flag_bits` set.

Answer (score 1):

How about defining `FindFiles` so that it takes `std::initializer_list` of `FindFilesOptions`.

```
void FindFiles(std::wstring const& pattern, std::initializer_list<FindFilesOptions> options)
{
  auto has_option = [&](FindFilesOptions const option)
  {
    return std::find(std::begin(options), std::end(options), option) != std::end(options);
  };

  if (has_option(FindFilesOptions::LocalSearch))
  {
    // ...
  }

  if (has_option(FindFilesOptions::RecursiveSearch))
  {
    // ...
  }

  if (has_option(FindFilesOptions::IncludeDotDirectories))
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then you could call it like so:

```
FindFiles({}, {FindFilesOptions::RecursiveSearch, FindFilesOptions::IncludeDotDirectories});
```

Comment: Interesting. Now if the compiler I was using only supported `initializer_list`. +1

Comment: Then, just use std::vector.

Comment: That makes the caller unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @BillyONeal Instead of an `initializer_list`, maybe a function template with a parameter pack?

Comment: The function call (or constructor in your case) would be exactly the same. All you would need to change is "std::initializer_list<FindFilesOptions> options" to "std::vector<FindFilesOptions> options".

Comment: @Natok The ctor of `vector` that allows this... is taking an `initializer_list`. Same problem probably.

Comment: @DyP, you are correct, my bad. Well, the problem with variadic template parameters is that the types are not enforced to be of the same type; not sure if it's a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the explicit enum type but the class scope.

With C++11, enum as compile time constant loose a lot of interest compared to a bunch of constexpr when you need operate on the value ( bitwise operation, incrementation, etc)

Comment: Making the values `constexpr`s would allow someone to pass in any old integral type to `FindFiles`, which I do not want to allow.

Comment: I was a bit fast, the idea is to write a small template wrapper over a scalar type, taking a second class type as a tag ( like iterator_category ) to prevent mix of two sets of constants.

Comment: That would require me to make `FindFiles::FindFiles(std::wstring const&, options)` into a template.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance, change your options to `set<FindFilesOptions>`!

Comment: That makes the caller overly complicated.