# Can a C++ enumeration be made bigger than 64 bits?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

In my [entity component system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) I track and query which components each entity has using a bit mask.

```
// Thanks to Shafik Yaghmour for the macro fix
#define BIT(x) (static_cast<std::uint64_t>(1) << x)

enum class components : std::uint64_t
{
    foo = BIT( 0),
    bar = BIT( 1),
    // Many more omitted
    baz = BIT(63)
};

// Operator | is used to build a mask of components. Some entities
// have dozens of components.
auto mask = components::foo | components::bar | components::baz

// Do something with the entity if it has the requisite components.
if ( entity->has_components( mask ) ) { ... }
```

I've hit the 64 bit limit of the enumeration. **Can a C++ enumeration (portably) be made bigger than 64 bits?**

---

**Update 1:** I'm aware of `std::bitset`, but I can't create a mask like `auto mask = std::bitset<128>{ components::foo, components::baz }` because `std::bitset` doesn't have a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list`. If your answer tells me to use `std::bitset` please demonstrate this usage or similar.

---

**Update 2:** I hacked up a function to create a `std::bitset` from a `std::initializer_list`:

```
enum class components : std::size_t
{
    foo,
    bar,
    baz,
    count
};

template< typename enumeration, std::size_t bit_count = static_cast< std::size_t >( enumeration::count ) >
std::bitset< bit_count > make_bitset(std::initializer_list< enumeration > list)
{
    assert(list.size() <= bit_count);
    std::bitset< bit_count > bs{};
    for (const auto i : list)
    {
        bs.set(static_cast< std::size_t >(i));
    }
    return bs;
}

// Which can create the mask like so:
auto mask = make_bitset< components >( {components::foo, components::baz} );
```

Comment: One option is to consider a bit field struct.  I believe the compiler will generate appropriate/portable code even if you exceed 64 bits.

Comment: AFAIU, an `enum`'s value is limited to the word size, i.e., it could be limited to 16 bits.

Comment: Our of curiosity, what are you doing that requires you to have more 64 unique flags?

Comment: @cmbasnett, It's for a game.

Comment: I see you've made 13 revisions and now the post is "community wiki." If you want to earn points from upvotes, flag it and ask the moderators to remove the community wiki bit.

Comment: enum is not the right answer to your problem

Comment: Is there anything more to answer here? It looks like you're well on your way. Note that you won't be able to modify the `bitset` after it's constructed unless you overload operators, and for that I'd recommend deriving from `bitset`. Also, note that the `initializer_list` may be longer than `bit_count` if duplicates are allowed, but you are not checking for duplicates in the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others noted, the storage must be a `std::bitset`. But how to interface this to enumerations? Use operator overloading as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18554839/153285). The enumerators only need to store the bit index number, which buys you a little more space ;) .

Note, that code must be expurgated of shift operations, namely:

```
flag_bits( t bit ) // implicit
    { this->set( static_cast< int >( bit ) ); }
```

http://ideone.com/CAU0xq

Comment: How could I create a mask like the example in the question? `auto mask = std::bitset<128>{ foo, bar, baz }` does not work.

Comment: @DrTwox If `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` are the enumerators, you would write `auto mask = foo | bar | baz;`. It works exactly the same as the code in the question, not sure why you want a braced-init-list. See [IDEone link](http://ideone.com/kJ271Z) from the linked answer.

Comment: [It seems to fall apart when applied to my problem though](http://ideone.com/TAgSI0). The output is not correct. The braced initializer list constructor is what `std::bitset` is missing that would make it work in this situation.

Comment: @DrTwox The left shift operation (line 28) is overflowing. Needs to be replaced with a `bitset` member call. I didn't write that code specifically to handle large bitsets.

Comment: Thank you! Could this create a `static const` `std::bitset` calculated at compile time?

Comment: @DrTwox No, but the only reason not is because `set()` is not `constexpr`. The original from the other answer does allow compile-time calculation. This is a defect in the standard and I'll report it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `std::bitset`.

---

**Addendum:**
After I wrote the above answer the question has been updated with mention of `std::bitset` and some ungood ideas for how to use it, so far with 13 revisions.

I failed to foresee that there could be any difficulty using `std::bitset`, sorry. For it's just matter of not *introducing* needless complexity, of abstaining from that. For example, instead of the now suggested

```
#include <bitset>

enum class components : std::size_t
{
    foo,
    bar,
    baz,
    count
};


template< typename enumeration, std::size_t bit_count = static_cast< std::size_t >( enumeration::count ) >
std::bitset< bit_count > make_bitset(std::initializer_list< enumeration > list)
{
    assert(list.size() <= bit_count);
    std::bitset< bit_count > bs{};
    for (const auto i : list)
    {
        bs.set(static_cast< std::size_t >(i));
    }
    return bs;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    auto mask = make_bitset< components >( {components::foo, components::baz} );
}
```

just do e.g.

```
#include <bitset>

namespace component {
    using std::bitset;

    enum Enum{ foo, bar, baz };
    enum{ max = baz, count = max + 1 };

    using Set = bitset<count>;

    auto operator|( Set const s, Enum const v )
        -> Set
    { return s | Set().set( v, true ); }
}  // namespace component

auto main() -> int
{
    auto const mask = component::Set() | component::foo | component::baz;
}
```

or simply, without syntactic sugaring,

```
#include <bitset>

namespace component {
    using std::bitset;

    enum Enum{ foo, bar, baz };
    enum{ max = baz, count = max + 1 };

    using Set = bitset<count>;
}  // namespace component

auto main() -> int
{
    auto const mask = component::Set().set( component::foo ).set( component::baz );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note, you current code has undefined behavior, the integer literal `1` has type *int* here:

```
 #define BIT(x) (1 << x)
                 ^
```

which will probably be `32 bits` on most modern systems and so shifting by `32 bit` or more is undefined behavior according to the draft C++ standard section `5.8` *Shift operators* which says:

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

The fix for this would be to use [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) to convert `1` to *uint64_t*:

```
#define BIT(x) (static_cast<std::uint64_t>(1) << x)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or as Potatoswatter points out you can use `ULL` suffix which is guaranteed to be `64 bit`.

There is no portable way to use a larger type than *uint64_t*, some compilers such as [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) provide for a `128 bit` integer type but again that is not portable.

[std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) should provide the interface you need. You can use [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/set) to set any bit to any value and [test](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/test) to test the value of a specific bit. It provides [binary or](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_logic2) which should provide this functionality:

```
auto mask = components::foo | components::baz
```

for example:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream> 

int main() 
{
    std::bitset<128> foo ;
    std::bitset<128> baz ;

    foo.set(66,true ) ;
    baz.set(80,true ) ;        

    std::cout << foo << std::endl ;
    std::cout << baz << std::endl ;

    std::bitset<128> mask = foo | baz ;

    std::cout << mask << std::endl ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, better :) Note that `1ULL` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits as well. And, just for illustration, how can you declare `foo` and `baz`?

Comment: I think the key part of the problem is how to define `components::foo` where `components::foo` ought to be `1<<70`?

Comment: @MooingDuck there is no way to do that w/o a 128 bit type, which gcc does support but is not portable. The question has evolved a great deal since it was first asked. At this point, I don't think enumerations is the correct approach. Honestly, it should have been a second question after the original was answered.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: The current question, the original question, and the title of the question, all make reference to the fact he can't make a enumeration with the 65+th bits set.  That's what this question is all about